# Thumbnails on shared links

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, thumbnails, facebook-sharer

I am currently working on a rebranding with my company, and I am having some issues with the thumbnails which are appearing next to the facebook posts when someone shares our website. The issue is that our old logo is still appearing in the thumbnail image, and not our new one - not ideal. Is there an easy way of updating the choice of these thumbnails to give the choice of our new logo?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the correct [OpenGraph `og:tags`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) in your HTML markup and use the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to scrape your URL and refresh Facebook's caching of your URL; it will show you what metadata Facebook can see for your URL.